# Same Origin Policy with JavaScript extracting title

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, title, same-origin-policy

I'd like to use JavaScript with JQuery to extract a title from an HTML page, as in

```
$.get('page.html', function(text) {
  var pagetitle = $(text).title;
});
```

so that when the user input a URL into a text box, I can show the title in another textbox. But this won't work if the page is outside my domain, like `www.google.com`, because of the Same Origin Policy. Is there some other way to achieve this functionality? It's not a crucial functionality, but I'd like to ask just in case there's some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to have a server-side "proxy" which goes out and fetches the page, then returns it to jQuery for processing. If you're running this in a client environment (i.e. a plain HTML file on your local PC), then there really isn't an easy way to do this.

A basic PHP script would look something like this:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($_REQUEST["url"]);
?>
```

Note: this is a basic demo of what you're asking for. Just this by itself could well present security risks of some sort. A better way to do this is presented in [this article](http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/php-class-to-get-remote-page-title-and-description).

Also, though I haven't run your code, I feel like it should be more like this:

```
$.get('page.html', function(text) {
    var pagetitle = $(text).find("title").text();
}, "html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it!

```
<script src="http://kincrew.github.com/xReader/xReader.full.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
xReader("http://www.google.com", "title/text()", function(data) { 
    alert(data.content); 
})
</script>
```

Take a look at [xReader](http://kincrew.github.com/xReader/)